# Rotating a cube around its center Y axis, works first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I've made a cube with html/css.

The first time I apply a rotation transformation the cube rotates very nicely in place around its center Y axis.

The second time however, the cube kind of "comes forward" and then "moves back" while rotating. The cube ends up in the same position, but the transition is different.

[image]

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-perspective: 1100px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 300px;
    perspective: 1100px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 300px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1150px;
    width: 1150px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    transform: translateZ(-100000px);
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1140px;
    width: 1140px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px black;
}


 #cube .one {        
            transform: translateZ(600px);
        }

        #cube .two {              
            transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(600px);
        }

        #cube .three {         
            transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(600px);
        }

        #cube .four {       
            transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(600px);
        }

        #cube .five {           
            transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(600px) rotate(180deg);
        }

        #cube .six {       
            transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(600px);
        }
```

Bit of Javascript to move to cube into a good view

```
$("#cube").css("transform", "translateZ(-2500px) translateX(-380px)");
```

JavaScript to Apply Rotation

```
if (direction == "left") {
        if (face == 1) {

            angle = angle + 90;
            $("#cube").css("transform", "rotateY(" + angle + "deg) translateX(2500px) translateZ(-380px)");
            face++;
        }
        else if (face == 2) {

            angle = angle + 90;
            $("#cube").css("transform", "rotateY(" + angle + "deg) translateZ(2500px)  translateX(380px)  ");              
            face++;
        }
        else if (face == 3) {

            angle = angle + 90;
            $("#cube").css("transform", "rotateY(" + angle + "deg) translateX(-2500px) translateZ(380px) ");
            face++;
        }
        else if (face == 4) {

            angle = angle + 90;
            $("#cube").css("transform", "rotateY(" + angle + "deg) translateZ(-2500px) translateX(-380px) ");

            face = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have different width on your cube panels!! you have fixed width in css but paddings increase outer width.
check to see if they all have the same width with your inspect element. try working around box-sizing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I inspected all the faces and they are all the same width, height, padding etc. Also that "moves forward" glitch sometimes happens to the first face as well if I rotate all the way around, or left then right.

Comment: it would be better if you had your codes online or on a fiddle, so I could check it.